# Post method in Angular 7 not work with Spring Boot Rest Controller

Tags: angular, spring

I can not recognize a problem with my post method in Angular 7. I have the error:  `Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/sendMail: 404 Not Found`.
This is my post method in the Angular:

```
sendEmail(email: EmailModel): Observable<EmailModel> {

        const url = `sendMail`;
        return this.http.post<EmailModel>(url, email, httpOptions).pipe(
            tap(_ => this.log('Category is stored!!!')),

            catchError(this.handleError<EmailModel>('addHero'))

        )
    }
```

And this is my post method in Spring Boot:

```
@PostMapping("/sendMail")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public String sendMail(@RequestBody EmailModel emailModel) {
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        System.out.println(emailModel);

        try {
            helper.setTo("saomi@gmail.com");
            helper.setText("Greetings :)");
            helper.setSubject("Mail From Spring Boot");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error while sending mail ..";
        }
        sender.send(message);
        return "Mail Sent Success!";
    }
}
```

When I send mail from postmen on this path everting work well on the Spring Boot:

```
http://localhost:8080/sendMail
```

This is my proxy.conf.json:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Rest API work well.

Comment: You're sending a request to localhost:4200, not to localhost:8080.

Comment: I set up proxy.conf.json and for other request work well. That not is a problem.

Comment: Post that proxy config then.

Comment: I did that. You can see now.

Comment: I see. Your URL doesn't start with /api. So it's not proxied.

Comment: I am confused, what I should to do?

Comment: Replace `@PostMapping("/sendMail")` by `@PostMapping("/api/sendMail")`, and replace `const url = 'sendMail';` by `const url = 'api/sendMail';`

Comment: Thanks, I missed this. Now work well, thanks.